# how to schedule something from cloud function

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, sleep, serverless, serverless-architecture

I have a serverless app running as google cloud function triggered by bucket object finalize.
at the end of the function logic I want to call another action (also function) after exactly one minute (or T time).
currently couldn't come up with any way to call another action in one minute and had to use sleep in my app.

the problem with sleep is that I have 60 seconds that the cloud function cost money while no real work is being done.

any suggestion on how to execute something from cloud function in T time  so I can just exit from function and save money?

keeping in mind I would like to keep it serverless and using GCP.

Comment: This means using another service and that usually also costs money. You can use either a state based design or a time scheduled design: Cloud Tasks / Cloud Scheduler.

Comment: Thank you John, however this is what this question is about.
my app already uses "cloud.google.com/go/scheduler/apiv1" but this is crontab style scheduler for recurring executions. 
other services I know of such pubsub do not offer any mechanism I could use just for that.
I understand each solution will have it's cost but I think it should be lower than sleep for 60 seconds inside cloud function

Comment: Did you calculate the cost for sleeping for 60 seconds? You receive up to 1 million seconds of compute per month free. https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing-summary/ The actual cost is not that simple, but the required details are present in your question.

Comment: We're already beyond free tier.
I'm looking for an engineering solution/idea not an accountant one.

Comment: Edit your question where you state "and save money?" I have not provided a solution, just comments to help formulate the best question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Cloud Tasks with a HTTP target task and `schedule_time`:

1. GCS `finalize` event triggers Cloud Function A
2. In Cloud Function A, create a [HTTP target task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#http_target_tasks) with `schedule_time = now + 60s` and `url = URL of Cloud Function B`
3. After a minute has passed, the Cloud Task is scheduled and Cloud Function B will is invoked

Comment: Thank you @Aleksi this was definitely thought of but the authentication mechanism is unsuitable for us as HTTP has to be some pre-shared secret/key.
Having that said, this is totally applicable solution.